# Create a transformation (XSL) to modify a heat (WiX) output

Tags: xml, xslt, wix

I'm trying to transform the output heat (WiX)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="WINSERVINSTALLDIR">
            <Component Id="Dak.IPTV2.Service.exe" 
                       Guid="DC327EF4-0456-4031-A520-46F5D8EE7930">
                <File Id="Dak.IPTV2.Service.exe" KeyPath="yes" 
                      Source="$(var.winServDir)\Dak.IPTV2.Service.exe" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WINSERV">
            <ComponentRef Id="Dak.IPTV2.Service.exe" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Using this XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- copy everything verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- except "Component" nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('WinServ_', @Id)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it does not work. What I want is to append a prefix (WinServ_ for example) to the value of the Id attribute for all Component nodes. After applying the XSLT the output is the same as input.

What is wrong?

Best regards

**Final Solution**
Thanks to Tim and Tom I finally get what I want: an XSL transformation to append to some outputs form Heat (WiX) to avoid Id conflicts. This is the final XSLT file (there are other similar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- copy everything verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- except "Component" nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component|wix:ComponentRef|wix:File">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('WebApp_', @Id)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You'll probably also want `<xsl:template match="wix:Component | wix:ComponentRef">` or, instead, remove all `ComponentGroup` elements if you don't need them.

Comment: Yes Tom, you are right, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not accounted for the wix namespace in your XSLT. In the wix XML, all elements are in a namespace, as declared by the default namespace element on the root element.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
```

Your XSLT is currently trying to match a `Component` element in no namespace, and won't match the `Component` element in the input XML which is in the namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
      xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- copy everything verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- except "Component" nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('WinServ_', @Id)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the `wix` prefix is arbitrary here. It can be anything you choose, just so long as the namespace uri matches.